Method to find algebraic elements
Which of following is true for x$\epsilon$ R

$ x^3$ is algebraic over Q implies x is algebraic over Q
There is an x such that x is algebraic over Q($\sqrt 2$) but need not be algebraic over Q
There is an x belong to R that need not be algebraic over any subfield of R
There is an x which is not algebraic over $Q(\sqrt{-1})$

Well I know that option 1 is true and 3 is false, for option 2, I am not able to find an element which is algebraic over Q($\sqrt 2$) and not algebraic over Q, same for option 4.How can I find such elements

Here is a MathJax tutorial.

I am not able to find an element which not algebraic over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$, and not algebraic over $\Bbb Q$ - this is easy. Take $x=\exp(1)=e$.

2 is false, as can be seen using the tower law linked in the Wikipedia article below. 4 is true, take for example $x=e$ or any other transcendental number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees

Sorry, I need to find an element which is algebraic over $Q(\sqrt2)$, that is at the same time not algebraic over Q

@Alp1091 This is impossible.

Ok, is there any simple way to show that this is false

You are correct in saying that $1$ is true and $3$ is false. Further, $2$ is false and $4$ is true.
For $1$, if $\alpha^3$ is algebraic, then $\alpha^3$ is the root of an integer polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Hence $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x^3)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, showing that $\alpha$ is also algebraic.
For $2$, we need some heavier machinery, namely a field theoretic way to think about a number being algebraic.

Theorem: $\alpha$ is algebraic (over $K$) if and only if the field extension $K(\alpha)/K$ is finite, that is, the degree $[K(\alpha):K]$ is finite.

We also make use of the tower law.

Theorem: If $K \subset M \subset L$ is a tower of (finite) field extensions, then $[L:K]=[L:M][M:K]$.

Now, suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Then we know that the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$ is finite. As $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2):\mathbb{Q}]=2$, we see that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2):\mathbb{Q}]$ is also finite. So $\alpha$ lies in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, making $\alpha$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.
A slightly less complicated way of proving this statement is as follows. If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, then it satisfies some polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. Let this polynomial be $p(x)=x^n + (a_1 +b_1 \sqrt2)x^{n-1}+\cdots + (a_n +b_n \sqrt2)$ where $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. We know $p(\alpha)=0$
Then moving all the terms with a $\sqrt2$ to the other side, we find that $\alpha^n +a_1 \alpha^{n-1}+\cdots + a_n = -\sqrt2 (b_1 \alpha^{n-1} + \cdots + b_n) $. Squaring and rearranging gives you a polynomial with rational coefficients for which $\alpha$ is a root, showing that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.
So any number that is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ must be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.
For $3$, any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is necessarily algebraic over the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (which is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$) as it satisfies the polynomial $x-\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)[x]$.
For $4$, take any transcendental number like $e$ or $\pi$. Suppose either of these was algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$. Then, by the same argument as in $2$, they would have to be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, which they aren't, as we picked them to be transcendental.

I understood, every finite extension is algebraic so you proved that $Q(\Sqrt 2)(\alpha)$ is a finite extension over Q thus $\alpha$ is algebraic. Thank you
